# Should vent directly above furnace be open or closed

Tags: hvac, ducts, energy-efficiency

There is a vent in the duct directly above my furnace.  This is in the air out side, not the return duct.

Is there a reason I should have this duct open?  It was open when I bought the house a few months ago, but this seems like a waste, heating and cooling the basement.

If there is a reason to have it open, should it be open only during certain seasons?  (Open for heating, closed for cooling, etc..)

This is an Amana AMEH800805CX.  (pictured below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the supply side.  Most likely previous occupants wanted to add a little heat/AC down there.  Is it adjustable?  If not you can add an adjustable register because you may find that the climate control added there was needed.  Maybe for humidity, etc.

Comment: It is adjustable

Comment: Well you're all set then.  If you have a little workshop down there and get a little chilly in the winter you can just crack it open a little.  I've actually considered adding one in my garage, lol.